# NT10 Kernel preemptive multitasking

Tags: windows, multitasking, windows-server-2016, esxi

I am taking an Operating Systems course in which we work with Windows Server 2016 and ESXi

Our setup is one machine running W2K16 promoted to a DC, one running ESXi directly on the hardware and a client machine. On the ESXi machine we also have two additional virtualized copies of W2K16 one of which is promoted to a DC.

The question was posed how do you, using one of your machines, prove that the NT10 kernel uses preemptive multitasking rather than cooperative. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a simple program:

```
volatile unsigned i = 0;

int main() {
    for(; ; ++i);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile it, and launch as many copies as the CPU cores you have. Your computer won't lock up, you'll still be able to run other applications (although with degraded performance). This is a decent proof that you are running a preemptive multitasking OS.

This program just wastes CPU cycles like mad, never [explicitly or implicitly yielding the CPU back to the system](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/350723/30263); in a cooperative multitasking system, this would lead to a complete lockup of the system (once the task gets the CPU, it keeps it for itself, never leaving an opportunity to any other task to run).

On the other hand, in a preemptive multitasking system you can keep yourself the CPU all you want, but the OS will regularly take it back (typically on some timer interrupt) to let other tasks run as well.

Comment: If the system weren't preemptive, it would require periodic calls to `SwitchToThread` (i.e. `NtYieldExecution`) to allow another ready thread to run.

Comment: Actually, in the bad old days of Windows 3 (and previous) there *was* `Yield()`, but you didn't really call it all that often - in general, many Windows functions occasionally yielded execution to other tasks. The most common case was `GetMessage`, which is at the core of any Windows GUI application and must be called quite frequently anyway to keep the GUI responsive. All in all, it wasn't all that different than if the whole system was a big single-threaded GUI application; stop the event loop, and everything grinds to halt.

Comment: Funnily enough, this model is all but disappeared - the usual JavaScript execution model (both in the browser and in asynchronous-IO-based stuff such as node.js) is surprisingly similar to cooperative multitasking. Block the message pump for long enough, and the page will lock up (but fortunately the browser will come to the rescue, asking to kill the script).

Comment: (although... [even Windows 3.1 had similar functionality!](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140912-00/?p=44083))

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. :D